# can we create an xml using SaxParser

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, jaxb, sax

I Have a requirement to merge two xml files by comparing a particular attribute id.I am new to XMLParsing. I used SAXParser to  parse the xmls. I don't know how to move forward with the merging thing.  Could anyone suggest a proper and better way to merge two xml files. The output of this requirement should be a new xml document. I am also supposed to  keep performance in mind.

Answer (score 0):

SAX is obviously better in terms of performance. Without code, I can only point to some useful article.

```
http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=221
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way parse XML using standard APIs is with StAX (`javax.xml.stream`). You could have an instance `XMLStreamReader` for each input document and write the result to a single `XMLStreamWriter`.

Depending upon how complicated your merge logic is you could bring all our part of your input XML into domain objects using JAXB and then still marshal to the `XMLStreamWriter`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Can we just use Stax parser to merge two xmls without using jaxb. Like reading from two XMLEventReader and writing to one XMLStreamWriter.

Comment: @user1669614 - Yes, I think there are good APIs for moving data between an `XMLEventReader` and an `XMLEventWriter`.